# float_info : maximum number of decimal digits that can be faithfully represented

Tags: python

I was reading on the attribute `sys.float_info.dig` that is descirbed as :

> maximum number of decimal digits that can be faithfully represented in a float;

This examples showcases that float representation's are stable with  :

```
import sys
s = '3.14159265358979'
format(float(s), '.15g') #Conversion float and back -> same value
>>'3.14159265358979'
```

For strings that have more than 15 significant digits (which is deduced by `sys.float_info.dig`) the result goes into precision errors.

```
s = '9876543211234567'      # 16 significant digits is too many!
format(float(s), '.16g')    # conversion changes value !!
>>'9876543211234568'
```

So in this context, what does "**faithfully**" mean? Does it mean that if the significant digits are lower than `sys.float_info.dig` we are always guaranteed that there will be no precision errors?

Answer (score 4):

"Faithfully" means only that the internal representation can still distinguish properly among the 10^n numbers that humans intend with that quantity of digits.  In this particular example, it means that the computer will correctly round each of its internal values to a specific, human-expected 15-digit number, for *all* 10^15 numbers.

When we add one digit, it can no longer distinguish all the combinations: it doesn't have 10^16 sequences of bits.  In this case, adjacent numbers get mapped to the same bit pattern; on converting back, we don't know which of the several possibilities was the original, and the conversion routine picks the one closest to the binary representation.

In any case, it does *not* mean that there will be no errors with 15-digit accuracy.  We can still see plenty of problems with accumulated error when we combine numbers.  For instance, binary cannot represent the fraction 1/3 perfectly.  Try adding up 1/3, say, three thousand times, and you'll see the accumulated diversion from the expected result of 1000.0

Answer (score 2):

It means that if you have a string `s` representing a decimal float of the form

```
 mantissa "e" exponent
```

where

- `mantissa` has no more than 15 digits
- `float(s)` does not overflow to an infinity, underflow to a 0, *and* doesn't yield a subnormal number

then printing `float(s)` to 15 significant digits will yield a string representing the same mathematical value as `s` represents.  And it means that this wordy mess isn't always true for any integer greater than 15.

About the "doesn't yield a subnormal" part, behold:

```
>>> 3e-324
5e-324
```

It's easy to find examples for which 16 digits doesn't work, and you already found one.  But it's not easy to prove that it *will* always work for 15 digits.  Finite floating point numbers are a "lumpy" subset of rational numbers, where the gap between representable floats varies depending on magnitude.  A correct proof generally requires looking at each possible range of floats, as sketched here:

http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-precision-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/